# Request body HTTP PUT sampler not sent

Tags: smartmeter

Recently I started using SmartMeter. Everything seems to work fine for other requests, but if I try to use the HTTP request sampler to test a PUT request the request body is not visible in the request:

`<actual file content, not shown here>`

Now I've searched the internet and it seems this was an recent issue with JMeter that should be fixed in v3.1, is this the same issue in SmartMeter and how should I be able to fix it?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to this issue https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60092. It has indeed been resolved in JMeter 3.1. Use SmartMeter 1.3.0 or newer.